# set Zoom on only Cliping canvas area in fabricJs 2.3.4

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to set zoom in-out canvas but only in cliping area.

Check zoom function on this link: https://www.discountmugs.com/design-lab/design.php?product=TOT28&mode=2d&color=Natural&quantity=100&click_instance_id=85119304

Comment: I guess you can change the `scaleX` and `scaleY` of the objects  in the clipping area. I also saw tha you have some bugs there..try to move a rotated object...the margins are not the clipping area anymore.

Comment: clipping area is base on product so it is every time different. so how can i  display zoom that part.
please check reference link and help me how can i implement that type of functionality. we can also set some margin.

Comment: I saw your product...my idea is when you press zoom you can scale the clipping area using `scaleX` and `scaleY`properties on the objects

Comment: So. when you have a zoom of 150% you need to multiply the scale with 1.5

Comment: When i scale it will be display large. but how can i set every product on fixed canvas height width. you understand my query ?

Comment: @MariusTurcu Please check i have create demo http://jsfiddle.net/qsu4vbph/1/
please help to find correct solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191657/discussion-between-marius-turcu-and-bansari-savasani).

Comment: @MariusTurcu Okay